# Using CakePHP's Form helper to generate a drop down list and add a custom class

Tags: cakephp, select

I'm trying to generate an HTML `select` element for filtering purposes on my CakePHP 2.2 website.

Here's the code I run in my **View**:

```
echo $this->Form->input('proveedor_id', array(
    'type' => 'select', 
    'options' => $proveedores,
    'div' => array('class' => 'asd')
));
```

However the generated `select` element does not have the class I want `asd`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting the class on the div. If you want the class on the select it is

```
echo $this->Form->input('proveedor_id', array(
    'type' => 'select', 
    'options' => $proveedores,
    'class' => 'asd'
));
```